# Fitting on Diffraction Pattern, NonlinearModelFit, Complex Infinity

Tags: fitting, nonlinear

I'm trying to fit the function
$f(x;a,b,s)=a\left( \frac{\sin\left(b \sin(s x) \right)}{b \sin(s x)} \right)^2 $
on the data below using `NonlinearModelFit` but I'm getting an error message: Indeterminate expression, Complex infinity.

```
Ord = Array[1. # &, 21, -10];
Int = {1.233, 1.725, 1.737, 0.941, 0.453, 2.297, 11.06, 24.05, 41.6, 
58.8, 1630, 55.7, 39.0, 26.7, 12.98, 2.936, 0.472, 1.11, 2.21, 
2.38, 1.725};
OrdInt = Transpose[{Ord, Int}];
NonlinearModelFit[OrdInt,{a (Sin[ b Sin[s x/2]/(Sin[s x]/2))^2,50<a<70&&20<b<50&&0.02<s<0.05}, 
{a,b,s},x]
```

Does anyone know how to fix this or anyother way to do this fit ?

Comment: It might have to do with `0` being one of the x values.

Comment: Replace `0.` in  `Ord` to `0.001` for example.

Comment: Why aren't you using `Sinc[]`?

Comment: Hi @Physor,  Thanks for accepting my answer, but I think you were too hasty doing that. While *accepting* is one of the [things to do after your question is answered](https://wolfr.am/v57DB3p4), we recommend that users should **test answers before [voting](https://wolfr.am/v57ItzJq)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](https://wolfr.am/v57LwTXD)** the best one. That allows people in all timezones to answer your question and an opportunity for other users to point out alternatives, caveats or limitations of the available answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Evaluating your function around zero is complicated, better calculate the [`Limit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Limit.html) and make it an explicit part of the definition.

```
Limit[
    a (Sin[ b Sin[s x/2]]/(Sin[s x]/2))^2
    , x -> 0
]
```

> ```
> a  b^2
> ```

Also, you can restrict your function to be evaluated only for [`NumericQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericQ.html) arguments and avoid some problems with the symbolic evaluation.

```
ClearAll[f];
f[a_,b_,s_][0.|0] = a  b^2
f[a_,b_,s_][x_?NumericQ] := a (Sin[ b Sin[s x/2]]/(Sin[s x]/2))^2
```

Now you can do the fitting with [`NonlinearModelFit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html), and reasonable initial guess and constraints.

```
fit=NonlinearModelFit[
    OrdInt
    ,{
        f[a,b,s][x],
        And[
            40 < a b^2 < 70,
            0  < s < 0.1,
            20 < b < 40
        ]
    }
    ,{
        {a, 0.04},
        {b, 40},
        {s, 0.03}
    }
    ,x
]
```

And [`Plot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html)

```
Show[
    ListPlot[
        OrdInt
        , PlotTheme -> "Scientific"
        , PlotStyle -> Blue
    ],
    Plot[
        fit[x]
        , {x,-10,10}
        , PlotStyle->Red
    ]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Did you omit that data point with x=0 in your fit ?

Comment: @Physor no, I did not omit any data, but that point (`{0., 1630}` ) is well above the plot range. Your fitting equation has problems, anyhow. I think my answer addresses your question, but it is not necessarily a good fit for your data and does not endorse the function you are using.

Comment: Where can I find more about this piece of code ```f[a_,b_,s_][0.|0]``` ? I've never seen that in the definition of functions before

Comment: @Physor, Read about [Function definitions](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/function-definitions/) and the [`Alternatives`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Alternatives.html) operator (`|`). `f[0.|0] = c` means `f` evaluate on Machine Precision  `0.0` or exact `0` .

Answer (score 5):

Using the hint by @J.M.'spersistentexhaustion, we set the fit function to `Sinc` and set the restriction `a > 0, b > 0, 0 < s < .1` instead of presupposing `50 < a < 70,20 < b < 50,0.02 < s < 0.05`.

- **Add a translation x -> x + δ**

```
Clear[fit];
fit = NonlinearModelFit[
  OrdInt, {a (Sinc[b Sin[s x/2]])^2 /. x -> x + δ, a > 0, 
   b > 0, 0 < s < .1, 0 < δ < .1}, {a, b, s, δ}, x]
Show[ListPlot[OrdInt, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", PlotStyle -> Blue, 
  PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot[fit[x], {x, -10, 10}, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image]

- **NMinimize**

```
Ord = Array[1. # &, 21, -10];
Int = {1.233, 1.725, 1.737, 0.941, 0.453, 2.297, 11.06, 24.05, 41.6, 
   58.8, 1630, 55.7, 39.0, 26.7, 12.98, 2.936, 0.472, 1.11, 2.21, 
   2.38, 1.725};
OrdInt = Transpose[{Ord, Int}];
fitfun[x_] = a (Sinc[b Sin[s x/2]])^2;
sol = NMinimize[{Dot[fitfun /@ Ord - Int, fitfun /@ Ord - Int], a > 0,
    b > 0, 0 < s < .1}, {a, b, s}, Method -> Automatic]
Show[ListPlot[OrdInt, PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot[fitfun[x] /. sol[[2]], {x, -10, 10}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
  PlotRange -> All]]
```

> `{33.1874, {a -> 1629.95, b -> 178.54, s -> 0.0294933}}`

[image]

Comment: The point at $x=0$ is quite bad. It makes it impossible for the model function to be fitted well on the data. But thanks for the answer. I'll try to understand it.

Comment: This avoids using the NonlinearModelFit, it even makes the center point look not as an odd point.